# invalid pointer when using realloc to read from file

Tags: c, file, pointers, realloc

I need to read a file of unknown size into a buffer and chose to implement it using `read` and `realloc` as follows:

```
unsigned char* read_unknown_size(int fd){
    int buf_size = 1000, tot_read = 0, curr_read_size;
    unsigned char* buf = malloc(buf_size), *tmp_ptr;
    unsigned char* ret_val = buf;
    if(buf){
        while((curr_read_size = (int)read(fd, buf, buf_size)) != 0){
            if(curr_read_size == -1){
                perror("failed to read\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else{
                tot_read+=curr_read_size;
                if(curr_read_size >= buf_size){ //the buffer is full
                    buf_size *= 2;
                    tmp_ptr = realloc(buf, buf_size);
                    if(tmp_ptr)
                        buf = tmp_ptr;
                    else{
                        perror("realloc failed\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                }
                buf += curr_read_size;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        perror("malloc failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return ret_val;
}
```

At the second realloc I'm getting aborted with the following error:

> realloc(): invalid pointer

My guess is that forwarding the pointer that way is wrong, but otherwise the `read` overwrites what was already read.

I'd like to better understand the way I'm corrupting the memory, and what alternative can I use so that the previously read data will not be overwritten.

(`tot_read` is there because I also tried checking `if(tot_read >= buf_size)` instead)

**Edit:**
Thanks to mch for pointing out that I can't pass a different pointer, I've changed the code to the following one but now I'm getting

> realloc(): invalid next size

```
 unsigned char* read_unknown_size(int fd){
    int buf_size = 1000, tot_read = 0, curr_read_size;
    unsigned char* buf = malloc(buf_size), *tmp_ptr;
    unsigned char* ret_val = buf;
    if(buf){
        while((curr_read_size = (int)read(fd, buf+tot_read, buf_size)) != 0){
            if(curr_read_size == -1){
                perror("failed to read\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else{
                tot_read+=curr_read_size;
                if(curr_read_size >= buf_size){ //the buffer is full
                    buf_size *= 2;
                    tmp_ptr = realloc(buf, buf_size);
                    if(tmp_ptr)
                        buf = tmp_ptr;
                    else{
                        perror("realloc failed\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                }
                //buf += curr_read_size;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        perror("malloc failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return ret_val;
```

Comment: After `buf += curr_read_size;` you cannot use `buf` for `realloc` anymore. `realloc` needs the original pointer.

Comment: `buf += curr_read_size;` is wrong, for the above reason and because you are reading into `buf+tot_read`. After reallocation, `buf = tmp_ptr` as you have it.

Comment: `read(fd, buf+tot_read, buf_size)` ==> `read(fd, buf+tot_read, buf_size - tot_read)`

Comment: @WeatherVane but I want to read an increasing amount each time the reading didn't reached the end

Comment: That is the amount of room in the buffer. It is increasing because you are doubling the buffer size. I suggest you rearrange the code so that the reallocation is done *before* reading, starting with `buf = NULL`.

Comment: Note you are returning an incorrect value `unsigned char* ret_val = buf;` is the *original* buffer location before reallocating. I suggest `return buf;`

Comment: I noticed the things you've said, but somehow the read size stays 1000 (I checked with the debugger) @WeatherVane, can we continue in PM?

Comment: It will be 1000 for the first two iterations and then increases. First iteration `buf_size` 1000, request 1000, `curr_read_size` 1000, `tot_read` 1000. Second iteration `buf_size` 2000, request 2000-1000, `curr_read_size` 1000, `tot_read` 2000. Third iteration `buf_size` 4000, request 4000-2000, `curr_read_size` 2000, `tot_read` 4000.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree with you, but that's not what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to every one, I should:

1. `read(fd, buf+tot_read, buf_size - tot_read)`
2. `realloc(buf, buf_size + tot_read)`

Comment: No, please see further comments.